# Meteor Blaze Objectf

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like display object information with Blaze, but i've see only my loading template.

Structure mongo :

```
"type" : "formation",
"title" : "Title !",
"company" : "Company name",
"link" : "None",
"date" : "my date",
"works" : {
        "work-0" : "first",
        "work-1" : "seconde"
}
```

And my Blaze :

```
{{#each works}}
<div class="input">
  {{ works }}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

I can display all information exept works.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Create a helper that returns the results of `JSON.stringify(works)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may like to use array to store "works"

```
works:[{workname:"first"},{workname:"second"}]
```

Now you can use "each"

```
{{#each works}}
<div class="input">
{{workname}}
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you ! Work nice :)